# Oracle 11 - 18 enterprise edition installation in Fedora

Tags: database, oracle

For a college course I'm required to install Oracle Database, I may use any version from 11 to 18 but I need the enterprise edition. I managed to install 18c XE on a Fedora virtual machine following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880464/how-to-install-and-start-oracle-database-express-edition-xe-18c-on-fedora-linu), but I have not found an installation guide for an enterprise edition.

Comment: I would be suspicious of a course that taught oracle using oracle 11.  It has been out of support for several years now.  It was followed by 12.1, then 12.2, the 18c, then 19c, then 20c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Enterprise Edition is not certified for Fedora, so it was not tested on it, that's why it would be much easier to use Pre-Built Developer VMs as already mentioned in the previous answer or use Docker images, for example ready pre-built Oracle EE 12.2:

https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition

(in this case you just need installed docker and start it using `docker run` like this:

```
$ docker login
$ docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
$ docker run -d --network="bridge" -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -it --name Oracle_DB_Container store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

or built it yourself from
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Comment: I had a fedora VM with 18c installed, but I still felt docker would be a better idea, it looks like my arrow keys are not working inside the container

Answer (score 2):

[Database Installation Guide for Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/index.html)

1. download the distribution
2. copy it to your virtual machine
3. install following the instructions

See also:

[Oracle Database Software Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html#19c)

[Pre-Built Developer VMs](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html)